# Export a 'PPTX' format file to 'SVG' format files using VBA in the PowerPoint Application

Tags: vba, svg, export, powerpoint, pywin32

A 'pptx' format file should be able to export to a 'svg' file or some 'svg' files (just one slide to one 'svg' file) in the latest version of PowerPoint(the function is newly in the September of 2019), I can do it in PowerPoint Application. But I can not do it with the VBA in  PowerPoint Application, however I can export the 'pptx' format file to a 'png' or 'jpg' or another format file with the VBA in the PowerPoint Application.The code in the VBA is:

```
Sub test()

With Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    .Export "c:\Graphic\Slide1", "svg"
End With

End Sub
```

And I got this error:

> PowerPoint can't export the slide(s) because no installed converter
> supports this file type.

Actually what I want to do is that export the file by python(which use the pywin32 module), the code is:

```
from win32com import client as wc
ppt = wc.Dispatch('PowerPoint.Application')
doc = ppt.Presentations.Open(path)
doc.Slides(1).Export(file_path, 'svg')
```

And I got the same error:

> Slide.Export : PowerPoint can't export the slide(s) because no
> installed converter supports this file type.

The code is really OK because if I change the 'svg' to 'png' or 'jpg' it works just fine.

> 2020-08-26 Additional part

I have updated the PowerPoint to the latest version and use makepy.py which from pywin32 to create a new py file from Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library(2.c) named 91493440-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263Bx0x2x12.py, I have compared the old file and the new file, they do have some differences, see the picture [the difference between the new file and the old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcFbI.jpg), but in the "Shapes Export" aspect they seems to be the same, see the picture [ppShapeFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSViB.jpg). Anyway, I have tried the following code:

```
doc.Slides(1).Shapes('Rectangle 3').Export(file_path, i)
```

The " i " I have tried -5 to 20, but only 0-5 make some difference, the other exported files is the same with i = 1(which is JPG file), and I have looked around all the files, they are all binary file which can not be SVG file, so, how can I export Shapes to SVG？

By the way, I also have tried in VBA directly, and got the same result.

In case of the picture can not be shown, here are some key pieces of information:

```
    ppShapeFormatBMP              =3          # from enum PpShapeFormat
    ppShapeFormatEMF              =5          # from enum PpShapeFormat
    ppShapeFormatGIF              =0          # from enum PpShapeFormat
    ppShapeFormatJPG              =1          # from enum PpShapeFormat
    ppShapeFormatPNG              =2          # from enum PpShapeFormat
    ppShapeFormatWMF              =4          # from enum PpShapeFormat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is a relatively new format in PowerPoint and it hasn't been added to the object model yet.

As a workaround, you can export as EMF. Like SVG, it's a vector format. Then convert to SVG using [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-0.92.4/), which is free and scriptable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps a lot, I have solved more than 95％ problems, but there are left 5%. Some is that: (Below I just call the SVG  export by PowerPoint as "A", and the SVG convert from EMF as "B") 1. B is usually three times bigger than A, which sometimes can cause some performance issue. 2. Some effect like gradual fill may be lost in B but it's well in A. So I'd like to ask when will the SVG format be added to the object model, and how can I know it has been, for example, maybe from Office updated logs or some other ways. By the way, can't I change the line in the comment?

Comment: You can already export shapes as SVG, but it's probably going to be some time before you can export an entire slide in that format. Microsoft rarely announces additions to the VBA object model.

Comment: Please see the "2020-08-26 Additional part" in the Question.

Comment: As JohnK's mentioned, you can't use the object model to do something that's not part of the object model, and as yet SVG export isn't there, and Microsoft isn't saying when (or if) it will be.

Comment: I am just very curious about that how PowerPoint Application export an element to a SVG when the "SVG export" isn't in the object model, didn't it use the object model? If it's true, then how PowerPoint do this?  @SteveRindsberg

Comment: The application itself isn't built ON the object model. It exposes parts of itself to us THROUGH the object model. The application designers may choose not to expose some features/methods of the app, or the the object model/VBA development budget is so small that there hasn't been time or resources enough to expose the new features.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Did you reply something? In my page I can see a "show 1 more comment" link but when I click it nothing would change.    OK, OK, when I add this new comment, I can see your last reply, thank you, you don't need to reply this comment anymore.